# ssh to GCP instance fails after config-ssh setup: Permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Following the instructions on the Google Cloud Platform site, I have configured my local machine to ssh into my GCP instances via:

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
```

As expected, it sets up public keys and populates my ssh config file with the information about my instances. This step completes without errors or warnings. I am even given an optimistic message: "You should now be able to use ssh/scp with your instances."

However, attempting to ssh in results in failure:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Note that I am able to ssh via the GCP web console (the VM instances page).

Any guidance here would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, I managed to make this work by manually adding entries to `IdentityFile` and `User` in my local ssh config file.

Comment: Can you go into more detail and post this as an answer. Include specifics like which ssh program, OS, etc.